# False "Internal memory space is low" on tPAD - need a root access

Tags: rooting, internal-storage, insufficient-memory

A friend of mine has a chinese Teclast tPAD with Android 2.3.1. After some time of usage we start to get system notification "Internal memory space is low". Yet there are tons of free space in all types of memory: 14 Gb in SD, 5 Gb in NAND flash, 400 Mb in internal memory, 156 Mb RAM. Apparently something is wrong with the system because we can't install most of programs - installation typically finishes with a notification about insufficient memory.

From what I have read here, this can be caused by overflown hidden system folders, such as `/data` and `/cache`. So the question is, how can I get root access for tPAD, or how the cleanup can be done without root access?

This brand is not well supported worldwide, so it's very hard to find drivers and apps applicable. For example, I can't plug the device into a PC's USB in developer mode (if it could help) though the appropriate option is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kingroot. License is Chinese, but when you accept it, app changes to English. And you don't need a computer.
Then install ZArchiver. It can get to the system folders, if the device is rooted.

Comment: ZArchiver is not a suggested app for use as a root explorer. Other viable options include ES File Explorer and Root Explorer. Please link the apps mentioned in your answer.